# JToken.IsValid not returning true with numbers

Tags: json.net

I've taken this sample:
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/JTokenIsValid.htm
and modified it slightly to use a number instead of a string.  I can't seem to get IsValid to pass.  Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(@"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'age': {'type': 'number'}
  }
}");

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'age': 1
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
```

`IsValid` always returns false.  If I take `age` out of the schema, IsValid returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using an out-of-date version of Json.Net.  The release notes for [version 5.0 release 7](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113423) (October 14, 2013), list this as one of the fixed bugs:

> - Fixed schema validation of integer value when type was number

And in fact, when I try your code with the [latest version](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546), I get a `true` result back from `IsValid`.

If you can't update, I would expect that you can work around the issue by specifying `integer` as the type for `age` instead of `number`.

Aside from that, the only other thing I see that is technically incorrect is that you are using single quotes instead of double quotes, so your JSON is invalid, according to the JSON spec (see [json.org](http://www.json.org/)).  Json.Net seems to handle this OK, however.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the tips. The single quotes came from the newtonsoft sample...and using `integer` gave me an error indicative of it's non-compliance with the json specs http://json.org/ .  I'll look into upgrading our library.